# Не отображается фавикон в поисковике яндекс

Tags: github, favicon, яндекс-поиск

Я сделал простенький сайт. Залили его на гитхаб и опубликовал. Потом зарегистрировал домен на reg.ru и привязал его к гитхабу. После чего нашел свою страницу в яндексе. Короче проблема в том что рядом с названием сайта нет значка. В адресной строке он отображается нормально. Проверял сайт яндекс-вебмастером. Ошибок нет, и на против фавикона стоит зеленая галочка. Однако, проверка ответа сервера выдает ошибку: "Код статуса HTTP  301 Moved Permanently". А в суппорте яндекса написано что должен быть код статуса 200. Это необходимое условие.
код для картинки в тэге head у меня следующий:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сама иконка 16X16
Подскажите как решить эту проблему? Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: очевидно, убрать ненужное перенаправление.

Comment: какой инструмент для этого использовать?

Comment: судя по всему — ваш любимый текстовый редактор.

Comment: прошло немного времени и сайт стал присылать код 200. т.е. все условия соблюдены а фавикона нет. я ничего не удалял.